# Why oom may still happen even when overcommit_memory is set to 2?

Tags: linux, swap, virtual-memory, out-of-memory

> 2: always check, never overcommit

> > In  mode  2  (available  since Linux  2.6),  the  total
> > virtual   address   space   that   can   be   allocated
> > (CommitLimit in /proc/meminfo) is calculated as

```
          CommitLimit = (total_RAM - total_huge_TLB) *
                        overcommit_ratio / 100 + total_swap
```

IIUC, `echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory` disables overcommit, so it should never allow allocate more virtual memory than the actual physical memory(ram + swap). But when playing fuzzy testing trinity, it still reports out of memory and kills my desktop environment.

One possible reason I guess is `always check, never overcommit` is for per process to never allocate more than `CommitLimit`, but there is still proness that multiple processes allocate memory simultaneously and the sum is more than `CommitLimit`, is my guess right?

Comment: Could you confirm what you mean by "reports out of memory".  Ideally [edit] your question to include a snipped from your logs.